# Changing a raster stack projection in R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, netcdf

Doubled question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44726971/changing-a-raster-stack-projection-in-r?noredirect=1#comment76436491_44726971)

I have a NetCDF (nc) file I'm using to create a Raster stack in R.  The coord. ref. is listed as "NA" when I load it in, but plots as Polar Stereographic.

When I try set its CRS, it lists that it has changed in the Raster info, but still plots incorrectly.  How do I change the CRS to WGS1984 and plot it as Equirectangular?

I need to crop it using lat/long coordinates etc, so can't really leave it as stereographic projection.

Data is available here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz0W7Ut_SNfjeE9ObXpySzJ5UWs/view

Code used is:

```
  library(ncdf4)
  library (raster)
  library(sp)
  nc<-nc_open('NOAA_Snow_JanJune2016.nc')
  print(nc)
  varname<-names(nc$var)
  r<-stack('NOAA_Snow_JanJune2016.nc',varname='snow_cover_extent')

  crs(r) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
  plot(r[[1]])
```

(I can provide images of plots etc if you don't want to run the above)

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/44726971/820534

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the help obrl_soil, it prompted me to solve it using CDO (Climate Data Operators), using the reprojection function.

For anyone else running into problems with NetCDF files using horrible grids, I highly recommend CDO, whereby you can change it to the grid of another .nc file using the -remapbil function.  Solved here:
[CDO Solution](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/2/topics/5040?r=5065#message-5065)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the projectRaster() function to reproject the data rather than simply assigning a crs. First you should assign the dataset's native crs (assuming you know it, try checking the metadata or run [gdalinfo](http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html) on the on disk file) and then reproject to WGS84. Be careful to choose an appropriate resampling option. If none of the available options suit, you may be better off reprojecting using [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) (in fact, this will probably be a lot faster, raster reprojection in R is pretty slow for large datasets).

Edit: having had a closer look at your data, I don't know if it can be reprojected the way you want. The 'lat' and 'long' values in the file aren't - they're just grid coords (c(1,1) etc) from top-left, so there's no proper 'from' data. Suggest you contact the dataset originators, the full metadata for your file is, I think, here - https://data.nodc.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/iso?id=gov.noaa.ncdc:C00756  and it has some contact names in it.